# How can I convert a HEX code of a Binary file (.exe/.dll/.ocx) and write to a folder as a binary file using BAT?

Tags: windows, batch-file, binary, hex, exe

I am trying to write a **BATCH** program which can convert the **HEX** code of the binary which is stored as a string in the batch program and then write to a binary **EXE/DLL/OCX**.

I have found a command-line program which can do this but the hex string needs to be stored in a file rather than a string inside the **BATCH** program.

```
CertUtil [-f] [-v] -decodehex {InFile} {OutFile}
```

**RESOURCE:** [CertUtil Command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732443.aspx)

Comment: `echo` the string to a temp file and run `certutil` on that.

Comment: Ya that will work!

Comment: Hex is wasteful. If you need to encode as text, use base64